# laravel datatables search in addColumn

Tags: laravel, datatables

I use laravel/datatables to list data.

I manipulated my datalist with addColumn function.
However I am not able to use search in view for added columns. 
Because search is working according to database rows.
Datatables works fine but in the view search area is not working. Because there isnt any **fullname** row in database table.

Here you can find my codes (I want to search for fullname but I can't)

Order Model

```
public function getFullname()
{
    return json_decode($this->getAttribute('delivery_adress'))->fullname;
}
```

OrderController.php

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
    return datatables()->of(Order::query())
        ->addColumn('fullname', function (Order $order) {
            return $order->getFullname();
        })->addColumn('city', function (Order $order) {
            return $order->getCity();
        })->addColumn('product_id', function (Order $order) {
            return $order->product->title;
        })->make(true);
}
```

Orders Blade / Datatables code

```
        "pageLength": 10,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: 'orders',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            { data: 'fullname', name: 'fullname', defaultContent: '-' , orderable: false },
            { data: 'city', name: 'city', defaultContent: '-', orderable: false  },
            { data: 'product_id', name: 'product_id', className: 'd-none d-sm-table-cell', defaultContent: '-' },
            { data: 'totalPrice', name: 'totalPrice', className: 'd-none d-sm-table-cell', defaultContent: '-' },
        ],
```

[image]

**edit**:

Finally, I found solution

```
{data: 'added_column', name: 'actual_column_name'}
```

https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/139#issuecomment-275326787

Comment: Please post your function in order model where to get getFullname()

Comment: I added my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found solution

```
{data: 'added_column', name: 'actual_column_name'}
```

https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/139#issuecomment-275326787

Comment: Nice share, works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

change status

serverSide : false

```
 "pageLength": 10,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: false,
        ajax: 'orders',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            { data: 'fullname', name: 'fullname', defaultContent: '-' , orderable: false },
            { data: 'city', name: 'city', defaultContent: '-', orderable: false  },
            { data: 'product_id', name: 'product_id', className: 'd-none d-sm-table-cell', defaultContent: '-' },
            { data: 'totalPrice', name: 'totalPrice', className: 'd-none d-sm-table-cell', defaultContent: '-' },
        ],
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to have relationship into Order model like this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Try to update like this :

```
...
    ->addColumn('fullname', function (Order $order) {
           return $order->user->fullname;
     })
...
```

Comment: I think you didnt understand my question. I dont have any problem with to list data. There is no problem. I just want to search in row which I added with addColumn function.